# Print issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, printing

I have a page pulling iframe. The iframe is having a vertical scroll its working fine. But when I attempt to print it, the print version doesn’t contain the entire iframe page in chrome. It cuts out the data information which is coming after the scroll down. Its working fine on Firefox and other browsers.

I have a frameset like this:

```
<FRAMESET ROWS="*,500">\
    <FRAME SRC="" name=Invoice scrolling=auto frameborder=yes>\
    <FRAME SRC="" name=Shipping scrolling=auto frameborder=yes>\
</FRAMESET>
```

I have changed the frameset to iframe(code is below) but still i am facing the same issue.
I am pulling two pages in these iframes. I want to show both the pages without scrolling.
So I have fixed the height of frame2.html iframe. So I have a scroll for frame2.html data that is fine but when I am attempting to print this in chrome i am not getting full data of frame2.html in printing.

```
<div><iframe src="frame2.html" width="800" height="500" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="yes" name="Invoice"  style="border-width:2px; border-color:#333; background:#FFF; border-style:solid;"></iframe></div>
<div>
<iframe src="frame1.html" width="800" height="300" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="yes" name="Shipping"  style="border-width:2px; border-color:#ff0000; background:green; border-style:solid;">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Need help.
Thanks,

Comment: Framesets are deprecated in HTML now IIRC and shouldn't really be used. They're a bit 1998.

Comment: i agree that `<frameset>` is outdated. If you must use it, you could perhaps define CSS rules for print media that increase the height.

Comment: @Billy Moat Can you guide me what should I use to make it work? I haven't used <frameset> for long. So if you can guide me will be helpful.

Comment: If you're pulling in content to your page from an external source then you could use an iFrame: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe